# How to enable `sudo` with custom functions?

Tags: sudo, alias, function

Recently I learned you can enable `sudo` for custom aliases as follows:

```
alias sudo='sudo ' # note: the space is required!
```

[The reason this works](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) is the following:

> If the last character of the alias value is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

My question is: is there any way to enable `sudo` with custom functions too?

Comment: what do you mean by custom fuctions? can you give one example of what kind of customization u want to make?

Comment: Here’s an example of a custom function: `function foo() { id; id; }` I’d like to be able to enter `sudo foo` to have the function be executed as root.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/177699/how-can-i-execute-a-bash-function-with-sudo does that help?

Comment: @Legolas Thanks, looks like this question is a duplicate of that one. Good catch!

Comment: @MathiasBynens: The solution marked in the link provided by Legolas is not working in my case.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: Can you provide the correct solution if u find it.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case what you're trying to do doesn't really work.

With aliases, there is pretty much just a string rewrite before the line is passed for execution.

So, for example, if you have

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias foo='bar baz'
```

then when you enter `sudo foo` the command line is rewritten to `sudo bar baz` and *that* is then what is run.  This is simple command line rewriting.

Now functions are harder.  They're not simple rewrites, but a complete evaluation; they can set variables, change directories, open files... pretty much do *anything* the shell can do.  And, importantly, they're run in the context of the current shell.  When you run `sudo myfunction` then none of this is possible; in particular `sudo` commands are run as a sub-process and so can't affect the current shell.

The work-around used for things like the `sudowrap` mentioned above is to try and automatically work out `sudo bash -c 'myfunction() {...} ; myfunction'`.  This explicitly calls a new `bash` subshell and then runs the function in that subshell.  The explicit call makes it clear that things like setting variables and the like won't work :-)  It allows for a limited subset of functionality.

The sort of functions you can call this way may be better rewritten as shell scripts rather than functions; then `sudo` can call them directly.  The example given at http://w00tbl0g.blogspot.com/2007/05/using-bash-functions-under-sudo.html would be easier by having `duk` converted to an executable

```
#!/bin/bash
exec du -k "$@" | sort -n
```

That'll then work as expected!